# WebExtensions Permissions to bypass the CORS check for AudioContext.createMediaElementSource

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, web-audio-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

The application I am developing is a WebExtensions-based audio [visualizer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API). The example from the Mozilla docs uses the user's microphone as an input stream to the AnalyserNode, but I want to use the audio playing on page in the user's browser.

To get the MediaStream playing from the active tab, I am using AudioContext.[createMediaElementSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource)(elem) with the active Audio element. As I have learned, the browser will respect CORS with this function (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is required for cross-origin resources).

WebExtensions can use [Permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) to [disable CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) for all URLs by specifying the "<all_urls>" permission in the manifest.json, which I have done.

Despite this permission, the content script executing createMediaElementSource still is blocked by CORS. The error message in Firefox is "The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence."

Is it possible to utilize a cross-domain MediaStream from a WebExtension without CORS interference?

Comment: where does it say in any of your links that you can use Permissions to bypass CORS for **existing** media elements - as far as I can see, only `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` will bypass cross origin restrictions

Comment: @JaromandaX Nowhere. StackOverflow recommends that users describe what they have tried and why it does not meet their needs.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought I was misreading the documentation ... I don't think what you want to do is possible in that case - happy to be proven wrong though :p